# returning a variable string in Py_BuildValue

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm writing the following as a test case in C++:

```
using namespace boost::algorithm;
static PyObject* strtest(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    std::string s = "Boost C++ Libraries";
    to_upper(s);
    PyObject * python_val = Py_BuildValue("s", s);
    return python_val;
}
```

The code compiles and imports, but produces what looks like a reference to a memory location.

```
>>> math_demo.strtest()
' X\x0e'
```

I was expecting `'BOOST C++ LIBRARIES'` as a return value

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `PyObject * python_val = Py_BuildValue("s", s.c_str());` ?

Comment: Excellent. That's the solution. If you'd like to post as the answer I'll give credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[Python.Docs]: Parsing arguments and building values - PyObject *Py_BuildValue(const char *format, ...)](https://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue) (or any other *Python / C API* function) **works with *C* (not *C++*) types**.

In order to fix the problem, use [[CPPReference]: std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::c_str](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

```cpp
PyObject *python_val = Py_BuildValue("s", s.c_str());
```